# How to prevent HSTS?

Tags: browser, https, sdk, hsts

I have a sdk and want to support both http and https, but browsers always force to https. I know that is good feature of browser but many websites using http could not use my sdk.

Does anyone know how I can prevent HSTS or a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSTS is activated only when the concerned website ask for it (or when the user add the website manually to his browser). So **if HSTS is enable, it's because the website support https** (HSTS header is only valid when set on a secure https response).

If the website doesn't provide http you can't force it. (and when using HSTS, all http request bypassing HSTS will probably get a redirect to https as an answer)

Note that if the HSTS header have the 'includeSubdomains' options, it will force https for all subdomains, even if they don't support https.

Last point : HSTS (and HTTPS) is a security feature, it's probably a bad idea to try disable it.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I finally found the reason, my domain is a subdomain under a enabled hsts domain and include all subdomain. I did another way to resolve my problem by using difference domain.

I know that is security feature but we need http in some cases :)

Comment: @thehuyvb in which case do we need http ?